# Spring Boot 2 not picking up OS environment variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, application.properties

I have set a few OS variables and would like Spring to automatically pick them up.

[image]

But this does not happen. For example, `spring.datasource.username` should have been picked up from the OS variable although I get this error upon running the app `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost'`

Neither the `spring.profiles.active` is picked up, hence I see this `No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`

Comment: You can find more information regarding variables here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: How did you set those variables? Are you sure they are globally available and not only in the shell? How are you starting the application?

Comment: I'm setting them up from the Environmental Variables under Advanced Settings. I'm running the application from IntelliJ.

Comment: Which environment variables...There are several... If you only set them for the terminal they will not work for intelij running applications. If you are setting them from Intellij. If you are setting them in windows, make sure you relauch Intellij before trying to run the application.

Comment: I have set  `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` under `User Variables` in Windows. I have restarted IntelliJ as well. Astonishingly all other system variables appear in the actuator endpoint (actuator/env) other than `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`. What is wrong ?

Comment: Well, I had to logoff and logon into my computer to get Spring read the OS variables. I'm clueless.

Answer (score 3):

Those environment variables don't look quite right.  I think Spring would be expecting them to be something like

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
```

as the actual environment variables.  I have been able to set other values, but they need to be in that format as an Environment Variable.

More details can be found at

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Comment: Okay. I made the change. No joy!

Comment: A handy tool is the env actuator, which will show where all the possible properties would be coming from.  That might help you determine what's being picked up?  Assuming you have those enabled, hit actuator/env in your browser.

Comment: I have actuator enabled but `actuator/env` gives me 404

Comment: So, assuming you added the above to the end of the URL where your spring boot application is listening for Web Requests?  So, if my boot app is listing on 8080, the full url would be http://localhost:8080/actuator/env?  That's the default location (I think)

Comment: Right. The same URL gave me 404 although `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health` gives me a 200 with status UP

Comment: Well, I got the env endpoint working  by adding `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` to the application.properties file but I don't see `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` in there although they are actually present.

Comment: Well, I had to logoff and logon into my computer to get Spring read the OS variables. I'm clueless.

Comment: So, it looks like you're operating in Windows.  Sometimes, if you have any console running, you have to close all the consoles for any Environment Variable changes to flow through.  It's kind of hard to determine exactly what happened, but does that mean you've been able to read the values?

Comment: I was able to read the Environment variables but I had logoff from my computer and log back in. Only then I can read new Environment variables.